# Getting a Table using Excel VBA behiind a username and login

Tags: excel, vba, web, authentication

I am trying to get a table from a website. The problem is that I need to login first in order to access this information.

My code is below. I have hit a road block and most of the guides I found out there do not work with this site. Appreciate your help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("H1")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            ' Clear contents of Sheet 1
            '
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
            Range("A1").Select
            '
            'Login to the website
            '
            Dim IE As Object

            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

            With IE
                .Visible = True
                .navigate ("https://www.gurufocus.com/forum/login.php?0")

                While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

                .document.all("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_UserName").Focus
                .document.all("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_UserName").Value = "Username"
                .document.all("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_Password").Focus
                .document.all("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_Password").Value = "Password"
                .document.all("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_LoginButton").Click

                While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Debug.Print .LocationURL
            End With
            '
            ' take the Ticker in sheet Blank cell H1
            Dim Ticker As String
            Ticker = Sheets("Blank").Range("H1")
            URL = "URL;http://www.gurufocus.com/financials/" & Ticker
        '
        ' get the data from the website
            Range("A1").Select
            With Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URL, Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1"))
        '        .CommandType = 0
                .Name = Ticker
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        '        .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        '        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        '        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        '        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        '        .WebTables = """Rf"""
        '        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        '        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        '        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        '        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        '        .WebDisableRedirections = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that Sheet1's `Worksheet_Change`? You're doing a lot of work with no `Application.EnableEvents = False`. The event macro is almost sure to try and run on top of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would suggest that you get out of the `Worksheet_Change` event macro as soon as possible. All kinds of things can go wrong while you are stuck there processing a length routine and launching an InternetExplorer object to scrape web data is one of the slowest.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("H1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
        'if this is Sheet1's Worksheet_Change then the following
        'would be more succinct and acknowledges that we are in Sheet1's bailywick
        'Me.Cells.Clear

        'Range("A1").Select try to work without .Select

        'allow 1 second to get out of the Worksheet_Change
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "process_Web_Data"

    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So all that does is trap and evaluate the event. If H1 is involved, it clears Sheet1 and launches a public sub (stored in a Module sheet) and gets out of Dodge. The sub launch is a scant second after being scheduled and that should be more than enough time to exit the event macro.

In a module sheet:

> I added Microsoft HTML Object library and Microsoft Internet controls to the VBE's Tools ► References for the following code.

```
Sub process_Web_Data()
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gurufocus.com/forum/login.php?0"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .getelementbyid("txt-username").Value = "Username"
            .getelementbyid("txt-password").Value = "Password"
            .getelementbyid("login_form").submit
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Debug.Print .LocationURL

        '-----------------
        'do all of your other stuff here
        '-----------------
    End With

End Sub
```

That is sufficient to get the log in page's *'That Email/username/password was not found or is inactive. Please try again.'* screen so the login process is working; just not the credentials.

As far as referencing Sheet1 from that public sub, the [Worksheet.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx), [Worksheet.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) or [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) could be used. I would probably opt for the codename.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I can't stress how much this makes my life easier. Thanks!