# Inserting Excel text in web form including brackets

Tags: excel, vba, brackets

I have a table in Excel containing different values, sometimes with brackets. 
This Values are then being copied to a Web-form with `SendKeys Cells(row, 4).Value`. The problem occurs when the value (a string) contains brackets - they disappear somewhere between excel and IE so instead of **PE (Polyethylene)** I get **PE Polyethylene**. This web form needs the brackets in order to recognize the value. Would there be a way to get the whole expression inserted?

I have tried:

> `MatGr as String
>   MatGr = Cells(row, 4).Value
>   SendKeys CStr(MatGr)`

and ended up with **PE Polyethylene**

Comment: There are much better ways to fill out a web form than resorting to SendKeys. Check some of the questions and answers in this site's [Internet.Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/internet-explorer?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=30) forum. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695446/getting-a-table-using-excel-vba-behiind-a-username-and-login/31696915#31696915) for one example.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using 
`IE.document.all("material[" + CStr(t) + "]").Value = Cells(row, 4).Value`
this didn't work first but now it seems to do the job.